# Replace dom content that is dynamically added by script after page is loaded before it gets rendered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Let's say that there is a page with script that appends a new image to the body with random time intervals, and I want to swap these images before they get rendered by chrome. The code below does the thing, but after the initial images are already rendered:

```
function swap(node) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img-shadow");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
      var img = element.querySelector('img#img');
      if (img && img !== null && img.width === 512) {
          img.src = "some url";
      }
  });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (!mutation.addedNodes) return
      for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
          var node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
          swap(node);
      }
  })
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true,
  characterData: false
})
```

Comment: 1) You need ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) and change document.body to document, 2) Your code processes just a single image with an id `#img` so all the rest of it is effectively doing nothing which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Note, if you want to process inside ShadowDOM you need element.shadowRoot.querySelector.